# Library that implements ENUM DNS lookups?

Tags: c++, dns, voip, telephony

I'm writing a C++ application that has to do [ENUM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_number_mapping) lookups (telephone number mappings via the DNS system, RFC 6116).

I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Is there a library the implements ENUM lookups ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A C++ library that implements ENUM lookups is PTLib (part of the [OPAL](http://www.opalvoip.org/) project).

Answer (score 1):

Not C++, but I have a Java implementation in my [enumdroid](http://code.google.com/p/enumdroid/) application.

It works from the base DDDS specifications up through DDDS in DNS and thence to ENUM as a class hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ENUMPlus](http://enumplus.org/).

Comment: ENUMPlus seems to be a consolidating service for ENUM services. It does have an Asterisk driver, but I really don't want to use an additional provider.